Positive and Negative Voltage Buffers with Current Buffers
I am currently trying to implement as the title says some voltage buffers with a current buffer for the output, this is so the output signal can withstand higher currents. Below is the circuit I currently have in mind.

There are a few requirements for this circuit:

VRef+ should always be greater or equal than VRef-
High Input Impedance
Low Output Impedance
Stable Outputs

The first stage conformed by R101 R102 IC101A IC102A D101 and D102 acts as a limiter for both VRef+_Input and VRef-_Input this ensures VRef+ is always positive and VRef- is Always Negative
The second stage consisting of IC101B IC102B Q100 and Q101 are two separate voltage followers each one feeding from the previous stage, Q100 and Q101 are in there to increase the current capabilities of the opamps (IC101B and IC102B), and the transistors act as a pushing stage for VRef+ and a pulling stage for VRef-, the only downside I see in here is that VRef+ is limited to be (12V - Q100_Vbe) for Vref+ and (-12V + Q101_Vbe), thus losing a bit of dynamic range
The last section involving C101 C102 R103 and R104 are capacitors to stabilize the output and dummy loads to enable the capacitors to discharge if no load is attached.
So my question would be if Q100 and Q101 are safe, because if I understood correctly the 2N2222 datasheet the Vbe reverse breakdown voltage is 6V, so if the + input voltage of IC101B, for example, this would cause the base of the transistor to go to -Vsat as the opamp would be trying to replicate the same voltage on the output and possibly killing Q100 in the process, the same happens to Q101. This is why introduced the clamping stage at the input, I know this would work with ideal components, but I don't know if this is a good idea for an actual circuit.
If this could indeed be a problem, I could include a push-pull stage for each output, but I am also trying to reduce the part count as much as possible while ensuring proper operation. I guess that a proper push-pull is required for each stage, but what are your thoughts?
Note IC101 and IC102 are supposed to be rail to rail opamps (OPA2244), Diodes are 1N4148, and capacitors are expected to be electrolytic capacitors.
Thanks for your time.

A fast falling input signal would still risk a BE breakdown because the output capacitor may discharge slower.

That is somehow true because It could discharge through the dummy load, but only a the rate set by the RC combination making it somehow slow with no additional load, I guess push-pull for each buffer is a better option

It's not generally bad to reverse bias the base-emitter junction, and doing so doesn't automatically damage the transistor, unless that causes excessive power dissipation. There is apparently some \$\beta\$ degradation (here's a maker.pro thread about that, and a short NASA paper), but it's more of a nuissance than a hazard. Your only real concern is current that would flow in the load if the junction were to become reverse biased, current which can be blocked with another diode:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I've also ensured that the base is held at 0V when current is reversed, using a large resistance. Of course this does mean that you have now lost two diode drops of output swing, which might be a problem for you.
Also, this arrangement of emitter follower and D1 inherently rectifies, so I wonder if you even need the rectification stage IC101A. This is \$V_{REF+}\$ (orange) with a ±12V sinusoidal input (blue), showing both rectification and the 1.4V loss:

The slow decay is due to C101, but without that capacitance rectification would be much cleaner. Still, nothing bad happens during the negative part of the input cycle.

I have read that repeated reaching the reverse break-down voltage of the base-emitter junction of a BJT, even when currents are not excessive, may reduce the beta of the BJT. In many cases the degradation might go un-noticed due to wide variations in beta anyway. However, if a device is on the low end of beta when new, minor degradation might put it out of spec.

@MathKeepsMeBusy That's news to me, I need to do some reading!

@MathKeepsMeBusy OK, there's a thread about it, from Spehro. I'll update the answer.

That link was to a paper. But I did find a thread https://maker.pro/forums/threads/beta-degradation-quantified.101689/

@MathKeepsMeBusy sorry, I linked the wrong URL, but the one you mention is perfect, and is linked to in my answer, thanks.

@SimonFitch First of all thanks for your reply, Indeed that the second diode voltage drop is not desirable for this device as I want to preserve the dynamic range of the output as much as possible, I guess a push-pull stage for each voltage buffer could be a better option, also It would reduce part count since it would mean introducing another transistor to each stage instead of a resistor and a diode, this second transistor would be only for ensuring the safety on this edge cases, I guess this could help preventing the beta degradation that is talked about on the papers linked on your answer

@SimonFitch I didn't feel this question was the best one for me to add some experimental data regarding reverse bias degradation of hFE. But I did some tests, and included them in an answer here:--> https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/724201/268467

@MathKeepsMeBusy +1 for actually physically doing that, It's a rapid and significant decline! If you happen to continue that experiment, I'd be very interested to know the state of the transistor after, say, a week, to see if the degradation halts/settles somewhere, or if it continues towards $\beta=0$. It's a bit scary that this happens, and I never knew about it. I wonder what I've designed in the past that might fail because of this.
